XCode tests issue: 'any Protocol' does not conform to expected type 'Protocol' insert 'as! Protocol'
Started adding tests to supplementary objects
Tested class code:
class TokenAdapter {
   private let tokenProvider: TokenProviderProtocol!
   private let session: SessionProtocol!

   // MARK: - Init

   init(tokenProvider: TokenProviderProtocol, session: SessionProtocol) {
       self.tokenProvider = tokenProvider
       self.session = session
   }


protocol TokenProviderProtocol {
    func getToken(_ completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void)
}

protocol SessionProtocol {
    var isLoggedIn: Bool { get }
}

Tests code:
final class TokenAdapterTests: XCTestCase {
        
    func testUnauthorized() {
        ...
        
        let provider: TokenProviderProtocol = TokenProviderMocked()
        let session: SessionProtocol = SessionMocked(isLoggedIn: false)
        
        let adapter = TokenAdapter(tokenProvider: provider, session: session)
        ...
}

class TokenProviderMocked: TokenProviderProtocol {
    
    func getToken(_ completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        ...
    }
}

struct SessionMocked: SessionProtocol {
    private var _isLoggedIn: Bool
    
    init(isLoggedIn: Bool) {
        self._isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn
    }
    
    var isLoggedIn: Bool { _isLoggedIn }
}

In tests I'm getting next error on line let adapter = TokenAdapter(tokenProvider: tokenProvider, session: session):
"Argument type 'any TokenProviderProtocol does not conform to expected type 'TokenProviderProtocol' Insert ' as! TokenProviderProtocol'"

If I do "fix", XCode adds  as! TokenProviderProtocol like that:
...(tokenProvider: tokenProvider as! TokenProviderProtocol, ...
and 1) it changes nothing - error still there; 2) XCode now suggests to remove as! ... code

Any ideas about the reason?

@matt your words makes sense at first, but marking variable with protocol type doesn't make it as instance of protocol. Conformance checked on assigning value step
Also I already tried next option:
let tokenProvider = TokenProviderMocked() let session = SessionMocked(isLoggedIn: false)
Same error in the end

Well, in testAuthorized you are saying let provider... but then two lines later you say let adapter = TokenAdapter(tokenProvider: tokenProvider... so your code wouldn't compile no matter what. There is no variable called tokenProvider in the code you've shown us. If you change it to tokenProvider: provider then the code compiles. If you are going to give us a heavily edited version of your code, it should be at least a version of your code that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Can't argue with the point, that I misused name. Thank you for pointing it out. Will fix in a minute. But it won't cause anything except building issue bcs tokenProvider and provider are in different spaces and there should be no conflict.
The original problem / question stays the same.
I see your previous comment is removed so, I'm assuming we can skip that suggestion and look in another direction in attempt to figure out the reason.

Also comment for person, who downvoted - could you please clarify the reason? I would like to improve my question to let others see it in the feed

The problem is that you have not supplied a [mcve]. As I told you in my previous comment, and I tell you again: if we make allowance for the junk in the code you have supplied thus far (the dots, the failure to include class closing curly braces, etc.), the code you have supplied thus far compiles just fine. You need to spend some time in a new project, whittling the code down to something that allows us to reproduce the same problem you say you are having.

Also we cannot "skip that suggestion"; if you are able to provide a reproducible example, the reason for the error message will turn out to be what I said in my original comment (i.e., a protocol does not conform to a protocol). I deleted that comment because of the provider / tokenProvider inconconsistency, which caused the code you provided to choke at a completely different point; we needed to get past that before we could deal with the actual error message (which so far cannot be reproduced at this end).

I suspect that we're ultimately going to solve this easily enough by using a generic. But we can't solve the problem until we can see the problem.

Found the reason and it was in absolutely not related to XCode's hints - File AccessTokenAdapter wasn't included in Tests target 
P.S. So confused, that XCode didn't pointed that out ‍♂️
